# pandas.io.data get_data_yahoo ^DJI retrieval error

Tags: pandas

I am using Python 2.7.3 in Snow Leopard with the currently (April 2 2013) newest version of pandas 0.10.1

I am trying to use the pandas Yahoo finance API to get stock values (the date in the query is not important here).

This works :

```
import pandas.io.data as web 

GOOG = web.get_data_yahoo('GOOG', '8/19/2004')
```

This does **not** :

```
import pandas.io.data as web

DJI = web.get_data_yahoo('^DJI', '8/19/2004')
```

The ^ seems to be the problem.  Yahoo finance replaces the ^ with %5E or maybe @%5E.  I've tried directly substituting these with no success.  I also found [this commit](https://github.com/nehalecky/pandas/commit/9a48b4527670ff56b8529c01aa961873bbd610d5) from 2 months ago, which seems to address this on line 232.  I had a look at my own pandas/io/data.py and it isn't quite the same and it does not mention this is issue.

Is there an easy solution to use the API?

I suppose I could use Beautiful Soup or something myself and jam the result into a `DataFrame` but I'd much prefer to find a way to use the API as it keeps it clean and the work is already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the source of data is missing. For example, the source for GOOG is http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG, it seems ok. Also, some symbols with "^" are also works, for example, http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5ETWII also works. However, http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EDJI doesn't work. Note that "^" will be encoded as `%5e`

And, what the link is broken? Probably you can find some answers [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Dow-Jones-Average-Error/1283975525000-e462d312-827e-3316-900e-c85f668f587d)

Comment: Interesting.  So it isn't a Pandas problem.  I'm not surprised, pandas is pretty nice.     Thanks, Alex

Comment: You might take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/data.py#L149).